# Pushing New value to Array of Objects while keeping old one intact React Js Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a JSON file with image Names. I want to store data in a Key-Value Object. I'm creating the key using regex to remove `-img[image No]`. I'm unable to store all image Names in the array. When I add a new element it overwrites it to the previous value.

How can I push new data in an array without wiping off previously-stored data?

**Data Document**

```
[
    "apple-img1",
    "apple-img2",
    "apple-img3",
    "apple-img4",
    "apple-img5",
    "dell-img1",
    "dell-img2",
    "dell-img3",
    "hp-img1",
    "hp-img2"
]
```

**My Code**

```
content.map((contentInfo) => {
  let key = contentInfo.replace(/-img\d$/, "") //Return Company Name without -i{Digit} For Example apple-img1 whould be apple
  let imgName = contentInfo //Name of the Image
            
  data[key] = {
      Images: imgName //Append New Image 2 Array Instead of OverWriting Them
  }
  console.log(data);
})
```

**Current Output**

```
{
    "apple": {
        "Images": [
            "apple-img5"
        ]
    },
    "dell": {
        "Images": [
            "dell-img3"
        ]
    },
    "hp": {
        "Images": [ 
            "hp-img2"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "apple": {
        "Images": [
            "apple-img1",
            "apple-img2",
            "apple-img3",
            "apple-img4",
            "apple-img5"
        ]
    },
    "dell": {
        "Images": [
            "dell-img1",
            "dell-img2",
            "dell-img3"
        ]
    },
    "hp": {
        "Images": [ 
            "hp-img1",
            "hp-img2"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will again be an array. In your case, [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the ideal function to achive it:

```js
const data = [
  "apple-img1",
  "apple-img2",
  "apple-img3",
  "apple-img4",
  "apple-img5",
  "dell-img1",
  "dell-img2",
  "dell-img3",
  "hp-img1",
  "hp-img2",
];

const output = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  // get the keyname
  const [keyName] = curr.split("-");
  if (prev[keyName]) {
    // If the property exists then push to Images array
    prev[keyName].Images.push(curr);
  } else {
    // If the property name does not exist,
    // create it and add the initial value in the format you want
    prev[keyName] = { Images: [curr] };
  }
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator to accomplish this task

```
content.map((contentInfo) => {
            let key = contentInfo.replace(/-img\d$/, "") //Return Company Name without -i{Digit} For Example apple-img1 whould be apple
            let imgName = contentInfo //Name of the Image
            
            data = {
               Images: {...imgName, key} //Append New Image 2 Array Instead of OverWriting Them
            }
            console.log(data);
})
```

This should work.

Comment: `Images: {...imgName, key}` spreads the characters

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator can be used for adding values to an array.

```js
content.map((contentInfo) => {
  let key = contentInfo.replace(/-img\d$/, ''); //Return Company Name without -i{Digit} For Example apple-img1 whould be apple
  let imgName = contentInfo; //Name of the Image
  if (data[key] == undefined) {
    data[key] = {
      Images: [imgName],
    };
  } else {
    data[key] = {
      Images: [...data[key].Images, imgName], //Append New Image 2 Array Instead of OverWriting Them
    };
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: code does not run

Comment: I think you'd need to check if `Images: data[key]` exists to run your code. For the first iteration `data[key]` would not exist and you'd not be able to read `data[key].Images`

Comment: Yes, use an if condition to check if the value is undefined. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution provided by @Amila Senadheera. This case uses the iterations of the `map` function to conform the desired output object. Even ist working, the output array from the `map` function is not used.

```js
 const content = [
        "apple-img1",
        "apple-img2",
        "apple-img3",
        "apple-img4",
        "apple-img5",
        "dell-img1",
        "dell-img2",
        "dell-img3",
        "hp-img1",
        "hp-img2"
    ]

    let data = {}
    content.map((contentInfo) => {
      let key = contentInfo.replace(/-img\d$/, "") 
      let imgName = contentInfo //Name of the Image
      data[key] = {
          Images: data[key] ? [...data[key].Images, imgName] : [imgName]  //Append New Image 2 Array Instead of OverWriting Them
      }
    })
console.log(data);
```